# Kawasaki Eliminator Throttle Cable Discontinued - Ideas?

Tags: motorcycle, throttle

The throttle cable (open) of my Kawasaki Eliminator ZL 600 (B3) 1997 is torn. Spare part number: 540121490.

It looks like this part has been discontinued. I cannot find any used parts online either.

What solutions do you envisage?
Do you know of any model similar to the ZL600 that might carry a compatible throttle cable?
Anyone have experience with improvising solutions to discontinued throttle cables?

Cheers

Comment: Try calling salvage yards for a used part.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have a roll of the inner cable aka Bowden cable and a separate roll of the outer cable with various ends. Meant I could make replacement cables for many things.

For odd ends I even resucued them from the old cable by drilling out the old cable and soldering in the new.

Usually supplied by larger automotive suppliers, something for you to search for.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably an aftermarket cable available. Also there are kits to make up cables (in the UK Venhill make a large kit for this). Failing that try the local classic bike places who can probably make up a cable.